# KeyListener error

Tags: compiler-errors, keylistener

I have a problem with adding keyListener to my aplication:

> `App.Game` is not abstract and does not override abstract method `keyRelased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)` in java.awt.event.KeyListener

I try create new public class `KeyAdapt`. It gives the same error.
Code of my application is the:

```java
public int x = 100, y = 100;
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    public Game() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics gDC) {
        gDC.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        getGraphics().drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
            y++;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
            y--;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
            x++;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
            x--;
        }
    }
    public void keyRelased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
            y+=0;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
            y-=0;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
            x+=0;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) {
            x-=0;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Should be `keyReleased`, not `keyRelased`?

Comment: Yes i thanks you but I found it before but I could not write a reply to your post. Topic closed